# asp.net vb - docx corrupotion on email receving

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

Im trying to send a Docx file via this form that I made, the email sends fine.
but the docx file gets back corrupted.. 
this is my backgroudn code:

'Add the namespace for the email-related classes
Imports System.Net.Mail

Partial Class SendAttachment
    Inherits System.Web.UI.Page

```
Protected Sub SendEmail_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles SendEmail.Click
    'Make sure a file has been uploaded
    If String.IsNullOrEmpty(AttachmentFile.FileName) OrElse AttachmentFile.PostedFile Is Nothing Then
        Throw New ApplicationException("Egad, a file wasn't uploaded... you should probably use more graceful error handling than this, though...")
    End If

    ' UPDATE THIS VALUE TO YOUR EMAIL ADDRESS
    Const ToAddress As String = "pelleg@shakuff.co.il"

    '(1) Create the MailMessage instance
    Dim mm As New MailMessage(UsersEmail.Text, ToAddress)

    '(2) Assign the MailMessage's properties
    mm.Subject = "שלוחת קורות חיים"
    mm.Body = Body.Text
    mm.IsBodyHtml = False

    'Attach the file
    mm.Attachments.Add(New Attachment(AttachmentFile.PostedFile.InputStream, AttachmentFile.FileName))

    '(3) Create the SmtpClient object
    Dim smtp As New SmtpClient

    '(4) Send the MailMessage (will use the Web.config settings)
    smtp.Send(mm)


    'Show the EmailSentForm Panel and hide the EmailForm Panel
    EmailSentForm.Visible = True
    EmailForm.Visible = False
End Sub

Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
    If Not Page.IsPostBack Then
        'On the first page load, hide the EmailSentForm Panel
        EmailSentForm.Visible = False
    End If
End Sub
```

End Class

its the sendemail.aspx.vb file.
any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

totally off the top of my head, but try setting:

```
AttachmentFile.PostedFile.InputStream.Position = 0
```

before you call:

```
'Attach the file     mm.Attachments.Add(New Attachment(AttachmentFile.PostedFile.InputStream, AttachmentFile.FileName))
```